# Image of a finite set in $\mathbb{P}^1$ under automorphism

Tags: projective-space, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

I'm having a hard time trying to prove the following statement :

Prove that for finite sets $\{ P_1, ... , P_m \}$ and $\{ Q_1, ... , Q_n \}$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$, there exists $ A \in GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ such that $p_{A}(\{P_1,...,P_m\}) \cap \{Q_1, ... , Q_n\} = \emptyset$ . (Here $p_A$ is the automorphism on $\mathbb{P}^1$ determined by $A \in GL(2,\mathbb{C})$).

I've tried using mathematical induction on $n$ and $m$, which didn't turn out to be any helpful. Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Having some issues understanding, though. Could you elaborate please? I'm following that an element outside the union of  sets of solutions of the polynomials would satisfy the conditions, but is there always such element?

Comment: Alright, so if there are only a finite number of solutions satisfying the system of polynomials, the complement of the solutions would be non empty, hence I can find an element satisfying my conditions. Right? But then if there are infinitely many solutions, it would become all of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, and wouldn't there be no $A$ left satisfying my conditions? What would my $A$ be?

Comment: I'm really getting confused... Could you be kind enough to write out your first comment in a little more detail? Sorry!